# Scan the directory for gettext strings and add them to .po file using the zerospam/laravel-gettext package

Tags: php, laravel, localization, gettext

Is there a way to scan the directories for gettext strings and add them to the .po file programmatically, meaning without having to go through Poedit to achieve that ?

I went through [the normal installation configuration steps listed in the documentation](https://github.com/zerospam/laravel-gettext#2-install), but when `php artisan gettext:create` or `php artisan gettext:update` command is executed, it only seems to generate empty .po files only containing the headers.

`laravel-gettext.php :`

```
<?php


return [

    /**
     * Translation handlers, options are:
     *
     * - symfony: (recommended) uses the symfony translations component. Incompatible with php-gettext
     * you must uninstall the php-gettext module before use this handler.
     *
     * - gettext: requires the php-gettext module installed. This handler has well-known cache issues
     */
    'handler' => 'symfony',

    /**
     * Session identifier: Key under which the current locale will be stored.
     */
    'session-identifier' => 'laravel-gettext-locale',

    /**
     * Default locale: this will be the default for your application.
     * Is to be supposed that all strings are written in this language.
     */
    'locale' => 'en_US',

    /**
     * Supported locales: An array containing all allowed languages
     */
    'supported-locales' => [
        'en_US',
    ],

    /**
     * Default charset encoding.
     */
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',

    /**
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * All standard configuration ends here. The following values
     * are only for special cases.
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     **/

    /**
     * Locale categories to set
     */
    'categories' => [
        'LC_ALL',
    ],

    /**
     * Base translation directory path (don't use trailing slash)
     */
    'translations-path' => '../resources/lang',

    /**
     * Relative path to the app folder: is used on .po header files
     */
    'relative-path' => '../../../../../app',

    /**
     * Fallback locale: When default locale is not available
     */
    'fallback-locale' => 'en_US',

    /**
     * Default domain used for translations: It is the file name for .po and .mo files
     */
    'domain' => 'messages',

    /**
     * Project name: is used on .po header files
     */
    'project' => 'MultilanguageLaravelApplication',

    /**
     * Translator contact data (used on .po headers too)
     */
    'translator' => 'James Translator <james@translations.colm>',

    /**
     * Paths where Poedit will search recursively for strings to translate.
     * All paths are relative to app/ (don't use trailing slash).
     *
     * Remember to call artisan gettext:update after change this.
     */
    'source-paths' => [
        'Http',
        '../resources/views',
        'Console',
    ],

    /**
     * Multi-domain directory paths. If you want the translations in
     * different files, just wrap your paths into a domain name.
     * for example:
     */
    /*
    'source-paths' => [

        // 'frontend' domain
        'frontend' => [
            'controllers',
            'views/frontend',
        ],

        // 'backend' domain
        'backend' => [
            'views/backend',
        ],

        // 'messages' domain (matches default domain)
        'storage/views',
    ],
    */

    /**
     * Sync laravel: A flag that determines if the laravel built-in locale must
     * be changed when you call LaravelGettext::setLocale.
     */
    'sync-laravel' => true,

    /**
     * The adapter used to sync the laravel built-in locale
     */
    'adapter' => \Xinax\LaravelGettext\Adapters\LaravelAdapter::class,

    /**
     * Where to store the current locale/domain
     *
     * By default, in the session.
     * Can be changed for only memory or your own storage mechanism
     *
     * @see \Xinax\LaravelGettext\Storages\Storage
     */
    'storage' => \Xinax\LaravelGettext\Storages\SessionStorage::class,

    /**
     * Use custom locale that is not supported by the system
     */
    'custom-locale' => false,

    /**
     * The keywords list used by poedit to search the strings to be translated
     *
     * The "_", "__" and "gettext" are singular translation functions
     * The "_n" and "ngettext" are plural translation functions
     * The "dgettext" function allows a translation domain to be explicitly specified
     *
     * "__" and "_n" and "_i" and "_s" are helpers functions @see \Xinax\LaravelGettext\Support\helpers.php
     */
    'keywords-list' => ['_', '__', '_i', '_s', 'gettext', '_n:1,2', 'ngettext:1,2', 'dgettext:2'],
];
```

`messages.po :`

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: MultilanguageLaravelApplication\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-09-16 11:59+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2022-09-16 11:59+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: James Translator <james@translations.colm>\n"
"Language-Team: James Translator <james@translations.colm>\n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;__;_i;_s;gettext;_n:1,2;ngettext:1,2;dgettext:2\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../../../../app\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: Http\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-1: ../resources/views\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-2: Console\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-3: ../storage/framework/messages/\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal process to update an existing .po file would be to extract translatable lines with `xgettext` producing a .pot file, and then merge it with existing .po file by using `msgmerge`.

To simplify the process you may use [POedit](https://poedit.net/) tool that will do all the above in a GUI.

See:
[GNU gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/index.html), especially Making the PO Template File and Updating Existing PO Files chapters